# scanf limited character set

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to read a input with the following format [A-Z],123 and store the result. For example 'A,123' or 'B , 456' (Single capital letter followed by a colon followed by an integer, white spaces allowed)

I was able to achieve this using several separate calls to scanf. But i'm trying to do it using a single call to scanf.

I don't understand why the following is not working:

```
char temp[23];
int a = 0;
int result = scanf("%1[A-Z]s , %d", temp, &a);
printf("%d = %d, %s\n", result, a, temp);
```

This code returns 1 and the variable a is never set. I'm compiling using `gcc -ansi -pedantic`

Comment: `"%1[A-Z]s , %d"` --> `"%1[A-Z] , %d"` and `"%d = %g, %s\n"` --> `"%d = %d, %s\n"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int result = scanf("%1[A-Z]s , %d", temp, &a);
//                        ^^^
// read 1 letter, a literal "s", optional whitespace,
// a literal comma, optional whitespace, an integer
```

vs

```
int result = scanf("%1[A-Z] , %d", temp, &a);
//                        no s
// read 1 letter, optional whitespace,
// a literal comma, optional whitespace, an integer
```

---

To tell weather the parsing failed because there was no comma or because the 2nd argument was not a number read the comma into a variable, then check it:

```
char ch;
int result = scanf("%1[A-Z] %c%d", temp, &ch, &a);
if (result == 3 && ch == ',') /* all ok */;
if (result == 2) /* a not read */;
```

<sup>*I seem unable to add a comment on this computer.*</sup>

Comment: I think I found a cleaner way of testing the delimiters, instead of `%c`, I can just do `%1[,]`.